# calculate average number of voters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| npop | wht | blk | his | bush | gore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 198326 | 74.4 | 21.5 | 4.7 | 34224 | 47465 |
| 20761 | 82.4 | 16.8 | 1.5 | 5710 | 2492 |
| 146223 | 80 | 12.4 | 1.2 | 38737 | 18950 |

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the average vote per county obtained by the candidates (bush, gore). I'm using Pandas to work with the datasets. Here's what I have so far:

```
def averageCandidateVotes(filename, column):
   input = pd.read_csv(filename)
   candidate = input[column]
   avg_vote = 
   return avg_vote
```

Comment: Average over what?  If each line is a county, then you have the actual number.  You don't need to compute an average.  What output did you expect from this?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, I'm looking to get the average votes per county for each candidate (gore, bush). right now what I have is the actual number of votes for each candidate.

Comment: That doesn't help.  Do you want the average over the whole table?  That's `candidate.mean()`, but "average votes per county" is not a useful statistic.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I just figured it out. thanks. all I needed to do was use candidate.mean() as you suggested.